Как запустить vbs с правами администратора, но без ввода пароля?
Имеется vbs скрипт. Его нужно запустить с правами администратора из под обычного доменного пользователя, но чтобы не вылезало UAC окно с полями ввода, либо если вылезает, то просто чтобы был выбор ДА или НЕТ.

Что значит "запустить"? Автоматически через политики по времени/событию, или сам юзер вручную?

Юзер сам когда ему нужно должен запускать.

Ну так создайте ярлык с соотв. параметрами...
